# PHP: execute an action after a given time

Tags: php, time, execution

Good morning/afternoon/evening, Internet.
I am currently developing a wap game and have encountered a problem: applying long-term effects on other players. Let me explain.

If a user uses an 'instant' ability, it is just a normal command link that does `executeAbility()`;
If a user casts a spell, the script does the following:

```
setPlayerState('casting');
sleep($cast_time);
executeAbility();
```

This is but a simple part, though. Now if we go to some more advanced techiques, like putting a curse on a player, I get lost. I've already considered the following possibility:

```
$time=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$time_when_the_curse_finishes=$time+$curseDuration;
updateEnemyCurses($curseID,$endTime);
if ($time<$endTime) removeCurse();
```

This might look pretty and all, but it doesn't take two things into consideration: if the user logged off and logged back in in 2 hours, he would spend the whole two hours cursed *and* this method cannot support *effect every x seconds for y seconds* kind of curses. For example:

Curse One. You take 1 damage every 2 seconds for 10 seconds.

To summarise, I simply require a tip or two how I could make the line above possible. The curse itself would need to have its time checked globally (not with page reloads) and be able to complete queries (in this case damage ticks) every x seconds until it is removed in 10 seconds.

I am thankful in advance for any tips offered here!

Comment: I think you want a cron job...

Comment: I've thought about cron jobs too, but wouldn't creating files for cron jobs every second for ~1000-4000 people online kill the servers?

Comment: Aside: are you using PHP's "sleep()" in your script? In terms of a UX perspective, this might not be a great idea (unless this is an ajaxy call..)

Comment: usleep, to be more precise. I know it's not exactly a perfect method, but it gets the job done *for now*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully understand your problem because here at work I had to deal with a feature that required a solution that might help you. What I did was setup a db table that stored all the required/pending actions and the owner of the action. This table had a timestamp and under a certain interval I checked what actions were required to perform for this user. Other users checked also that table and removed past actions that were not retrieved (i.e. the owner of that action was logged out). The problem here was what to do if no users were logged at all and what I did was that when a user logs in, it checks the pending actions table first and cleans it if needed. I hope I can give you some insight. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Correct me if I'm wrong: by following your example I'd create a table , with the fields `id,function,time` where `id` is the user id, `function` is the php code to be executed and `time` is the timestamp. With every click any user makes anywhere, the script performs a query: `$sql=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT function,id FROM actions WHERE time<CURRENT TIMESTAMP"));`, if there are any rows, perfrorms a `foreach` to execute the actions and deletes them?

Comment: Actually my solution involved a timer (it was an application under Adobe Flex) that checked the table every minute, you should check your pending actions every second and remove the past actions from other users. If it is a mobile application you could use some javascript to store locally your current/pending actions and just check those pending from other users. I'm sure that there is a nicer/optimized way to do it under your technology but I only had a shared host and php with flex to do this.

Comment: Since I'm trying to be as multi-platform as possible and most of the old phones don't support javascript, the only storage I'd have is `$_SESSION`. Speaking of which, I don't believe this would be a proper way to go as it would just search for your own actions and not the others', making 'ticks' laggy.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into setting up a cron script for this type of "maintenance" work.

It could run at a fixed interval (ie. every second) and handle curse etc. effects for all players

Start here :)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

**Edit**: As the others have mentioned (@mark-b), it's best to clarify: Use a cronjob for a single script that manages all of the work, not multiple cronjobs for each piece of work.

Comment: I restate my question from the comment box on the top of the page: I've thought about cron jobs too, but wouldn't creating files for cron jobs every second for ~1000-4000 people online kill the servers? (with no irony or disrespect, I'm just curious.)

Comment: It all depends on the script(s) being executed. And your hardware.. etc. :) 
It's definitely not uncommon to do something like this. If you structure your tables properly and have efficient indexing, it shouldn't be too bad at all.

Comment: It certainly is interesting. Will definetely try this along with An0n's idea posted above to see which one works faster.

Comment: As Marc's answer mention, you shouldn't be creating a cron job for every action, you set up a general maintenance cron job that handles everything at once.

Comment: That, however, might not be an option since I've just found out that CRON can only be set at a precision of one minute and the check needs to be performed every second (the slowest perdiod I can afford).

Comment: To be honest, I think your requirements would dictate that you have dedicated server software for your game engine.. something more elaborate than PHP + CRON.

Comment: I don't plan to stay on a shared host for more than two months; only during the state of open beta when there are no more than 100-200 users online.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be best to implement an event queue in a database. Rather than creating a cron job for every action that needs to be done on a user or by a user, you just add an entry to the DB job queue.

Then a SINGLE cron job can pull jobs out of that queue and process them. So for your 'curse' event, you'd set the curse flag on the user, and schedule a job to be executed at `now + 5 minutes` saying "remove curse X from user Y".

The cron job would fire up periodically (at whatever rate a 'tick' is in your game, perhaps) and request the list of jobs that need to be executed in that particular time period.

Comment: Marc, I believe you've just provided me with a perfect answer. There is one little piece of advice I need, though. What, would you think, is the lowest cron period I could set that wouldn't burn my hosting provider's computer? Would 0.3-0.5s be too low?

Comment: cron has a granularity of 1 minute. If you need shorter intervals, you'd have to do some in-script scheduling: Cron fires up the script, then the script runs/sleeps in whatever sub-minute intervals you need.

Comment: Would cron support infinite loops? E.g. `while (1==1)...`?

Comment: In that case, you'd want a daemon instead - a background job that doesn't exit. Cron is for short-term repeating jobs, stuff that starts up, does something, and then exits. Daemons would be a much better choice if you need <1 minute granularity on processing.

Comment: Which I doubt are supported on the shared hosting providers I'll be using in the beginning of my project, but I do believe it will become the way to go once it advances. If PHP is set to ipe out in, say, 65-70 seconds but the cron job checks the database every second 60 times, after which, the cron is restarted, a simple `function(); sleep();` would do the job correctly, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know gearman? I think, you have to create asynchronous jobs.

look at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but my project will be stored on a shared host at first and I will be unable to access Gearman, I'm afraid.